# Polymorphism issue with persistence layer and business logic call c#

Tags: c#, inheritance, polymorphism, persistence, business-logic

I am actually learning polymorphism. I have my business logic completely decoupled of the persistence layer using the DAO pattern, but now I am facing a problem when I am trying to access the business data in the persistence layer.

I will bring you a simple example

```cs
public class A
{

}

public class B : A
{

}

public class C : A
{

}

public class D : A
{

}

class Program
{
    protected virtual void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<A> alist = new List<A>
        {
            new B(),
            new C(),
            new D()
        };

        PersistenceLayer persistenceLayer = new PersistenceLayer();
        foreach (A a in alist)
        {
            persistenceLayer.Foo(a); // can't call it
        }


    }

    public class PersistenceLayer
    {
        public void Foo(B b)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("is B");
        }

        public void Foo(C c)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("is c");
        }

        public void Foo(D d)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("is d");
        }
    }
}
```

I need to loop around the generic class, that is what I have in a list form, that is what I can obtain by my business class controller. Now to get the subclass type and call the appropriate method I need to change the foreach for the next.

```cs
foreach (A a in alist)
{
    if (a is B b)
    {
        persistenceLayer.Foo(b);
    }
    else if (a is C c)
    {
        persistenceLayer.Foo(c);
    }
    else if (a is D d)
    {
        persistenceLayer.Foo(d);
    }
}
```

So now is it working, but I hate the switch or the ifs checking the type and calling methods because now I have 3 subclasses, but what happens with 20 subtypes?

Is there any way to do this without doing this ifs or switch? Is there some pattern maybe?

Comment: Have a look at the [Visitor pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern)

Answer (score 2):

This looks like a perfect use case for the [Visitor pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern).

```
public interface IPersistenceLayer
{
    // These methods could all be called 'Foo' without the 'A' 'B' or 'C' suffix, but I've appended it to make it clear which method is being called
    void FooB(B b);
    void FooC(C c);
    void FooD(D d);
}

// I've made 'A' abstract, because in your example there is no 'Foo(A a)' method so this can't provide a default 'Foo' implementation
public abstract class A
{
    public abstract void Foo(IPersistenceLayer persistenceLayer);
}

public class B : A
{
    public override void Foo(IPersistenceLayer persistenceLayer) => persistenceLayer.FooB(this);
}

public class C : A
{
    public override void Foo(IPersistenceLayer persistenceLayer) => persistenceLayer.FooC(this);
}

public class D : A
{
    public override void Foo(IPersistenceLayer persistenceLayer) => persistenceLayer.FooD(this);
}

public static class PersistenceLayerExtensions
{
    public static void Foo(this IPersistenceLayer persistenceLayer, A a) => a.Foo(persistenceLayer);
}

class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<A> alist = new List<A>
        {
            new B(),
            new C(),
            new D()
        };

        PersistenceLayer persistenceLayer = new PersistenceLayer();
        foreach (A a in alist)
        {
             persistenceLayer.Foo(a);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: But I need to modify the business classes to add these methods, right?

Comment: Yes. Your business logic needs to be able to save entites, it just doesn't care how that happens, so I'd include the `IPersistenceLayer` interface as part of the business layer. The business layer will still be decoupled from the persistence layer - you can change from SQL to MongoDB if you want, without having to change any code in the business layer.

Comment: What about if I need to Foo returns the type of the current instance? For example in the first loop iteration, I got the object of Type B, I want the foo of B to return another B object. That is required by the load or get functions that feed objects from a database or something.

Comment: The visitor pattern is able to be used with return parameters, so this could still work. However, I'm curious - why do you have objects of so many different types all in one list? I'm asking because sometimes when people are first learning about polymorphism, they use it to solve problems when it isn't needed, and end up making the original problem more difficult to solve.

Comment: I have a list of Skill. Each Skill has a cooldown. Then I inherited Skill to a particular Skill subclass. My business controller has a list of Skill to control what Skill is owned by the User. The problem is when I need to persist the list of Skills. My persistence layer gets this list and for each subclass needs to save some specific data, that is why I need to know the particular instance of each.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a function to the Persistence layer that accepts the type A, then checks which one it is and calls the appropriate one. This is better since you don't have to check which one it is every time, only once inside of the function.

It would look something like this:

```
public void Foo(A a)
{
  if(a.GetType() == typeof(B))
  {
    Foo((B) a);
  }
  else if(a.GetType() == typeof(C))
  {
    Foo((C) a);
  }
  else if(a.GetType() == typeof(D))
  {
    Foo((D) a);
  }
}
```

so this is basically a general method which you can call with any object inheriting from A.

This is solution complies with the DRY (Don't Repeat Yourself) principles.

If the idea is only to print which one it is you could also do it as follows:

```
public void Foo(A a)
{
  Console.WriteLine($"is {a.GetType().toString()}");
}
```

I used [string interpolation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/interpolated) here but you can also go without, it just looks a bit better if you ask me

And if you are a fancy man you can also add the function to the classes themselves as follows:

```
public abstract class A
{
  public abstract void Foo();
}

public class B : A
{
  public override void Foo()
  {
    Console.WriteLine("is b");
  }
}

public class C : A
{
  public override void Foo()
  {
    Console.WriteLine("is c");
  }
}

public class D : A
{
  public override void Foo()
  {
    Console.WriteLine("is d");
  }
}
```

Note that I made class A [abstract](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/abstract) here, since you don't actually make instances of A itself you can make the class abstract and only provide a 'template' for the actual functions which the inheriting members then [override](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/override).

I hope this helped, Good luck on your c# journey

Comment: The `Console.WriteLine` statement is just a placeholder so the example would be short. The class is called `PersistenceLayer`, so there's probably going to be a lot of database access code in there - not something you want to refactor directly into the classes themselves, as that introduces coupling between the business layer and the persistence layer.

Comment: Yes of course, However since he is just starting to learn about polymorphism we might as well give him some more learning material right? You're solution is great however it might look a bit daunting or confusing at first.

Comment: a new `else if` would have to be added in the `Foo(A a)` method for every new type inherited from A that OP have already mentioned about as: _but I hate the switch or the ifs checking the type and calling methods_. **Visitor Pattern** is the solution to this design problem.

Comment: With Visitor Pattern you still have to add `public override void Foo(IPersistenceLayer persistenceLayer) => persistenceLayer.Foo<X>(this);` in every new class, which is more work, with mine you have them all in one place. I am not saying mine is better, because it isn't. Everyone should use visitor pattern if their planning to use it for their job etc. However, if you're starting out I think it is better to go with something more simple.